# Spacing in between items in a flexbox

Tags: html, css, flexbox

I am having a flex container with an image and a text. The image is in a `<div>` and the text is within a `<ul> and <li>` elements. The `<li>` is another flex container to justify the text in the center. However, there is a space between the `<li>` container and the child `<div>` of the first container. Is there a way to remove the space and center it vertically? I used `margin-left:-4%;` to remove the space. Is it the right approach?

Currently this is how it looks:

[image]

Removing the space and vertically center aligned this is how i want it to look-

[image]

**CSS:**

```
.headlineContainer{
  display:flex;
  border: red 2px solid;
  justify-content: flex-start;
}

#myPhoto{
  width:10%;
  border: blue 2px solid;
  
}


#myPhoto>img{
  width: 100%;
}

#myHeadline{
  border: green 2px solid;
  list-style-type: none;
  margin-left:-2%;
}

#myHeadline li{
  display: flex;
  border: 2px solid gray;
  justify-content: center;
  
}

#myHeadline #name{
   color: #008080;
     font-size: 340%;
     font-weight: 300;
     font-style:normal;
}

#myHeadline #Tagline{
  font-size: 150%;
    color:#000000;
}
```

CODEPEN: https://codepen.io/chandeeparora19/pen/oNxBNqL

Comment: it is not flex but default padding on ul : reset it : `ul{padding:0;}`

Comment: like that? - https://ibb.co/cx341MD

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In the css, I marked the grafts. There is no space and vertical alignment is set.

Option with borders:

```css
.headlineContainer{
  display:flex;
  border: red 2px solid;
  justify-content: flex-start;
  align-items: center; /*add - vertical center*/
}

#myPhoto{
  width:10%;
  border: blue 2px solid;
  
}


#myPhoto>img{
  width: 100%;
}

#myHeadline{
  border: green 2px solid;
  list-style-type: none;
  padding: 0; /*add - remove space*/
}

#myHeadline li{
  display: flex;
  border: 2px solid gray;
  justify-content: center;
  
}

#myHeadline #name{
   color: #008080;
     font-size: 340%;
     font-weight: 300;
     font-style:normal;
}

#myHeadline #Tagline{
  font-size: 150%;
    color:#000000;
}
```

```html
<div id="mainContainer" class="headlineContainer" > 
    <div id="myPhoto">
            <img src="https://cdn3.iconfinder.com/data/icons/complete-set-icons/512/googleplus512x512.png"/>

    </div>
    
    <ul id="myHeadline">
      <li id="name">This is google</li>
      <li id="Tagline">Helps you search everything</li>
  </ul>
</div>
```

Option without borders:

```css
.headlineContainer{
  display:flex;
  border: red 2px solid;
  justify-content: flex-start;
  align-items: center; /*add - vertical center*/
}

#myPhoto{
  width:10%;
  /*border: blue 2px solid;*/
  
}


#myPhoto>img{
  width: 100%;
}

#myHeadline{
  /*border: green 2px solid;*/
  list-style-type: none;
  padding: 0; /*add - remove space*/
}

#myHeadline li{
  display: flex;
  /*border: 2px solid gray;*/
  justify-content: center;
  
}

#myHeadline #name{
   color: #008080;
     font-size: 340%;
     font-weight: 300;
     font-style:normal;
}

#myHeadline #Tagline{
  font-size: 150%;
    color:#000000;
}
```

```html
<div id="mainContainer" class="headlineContainer" > 
    <div id="myPhoto">
            <img src="https://cdn3.iconfinder.com/data/icons/complete-set-icons/512/googleplus512x512.png"/>

    </div>
    
    <ul id="myHeadline">
      <li id="name">This is google</li>
      <li id="Tagline">Helps you search everything</li>
  </ul>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

You should reset your `padding` in this situation.

```
#myHeadline{
  border: green 2px solid;
  list-style-type: none;
  padding-left: 0;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I added display:table instead of flex for the the headlineContainer and for myphoto and text I added display:table-cell and verical-align:middle

```css
.headlineContainer{
  display:table;
  border: red 2px solid;
  justify-content: flex-start;
}

#myPhoto{
  width:10%;
  border: blue 2px solid;
  display:table-cell;
  vertical-align:middle;
}

ul {
  padding:0px
}
#myPhoto>img{
  width: 100%;
  display:inline-block;
  vertical-align:middle;
}

#myHeadline{
  border: green 2px solid;
  list-style-type: none;
   display:inline-block;
  vertical-align:middle;
}

#myHeadline li{
  display: flex;
  border: 2px solid gray;
  justify-content: center;
  
}

#myHeadline #name{
   color: #008080;
     font-size: 340%;
     font-weight: 300;
     font-style:normal;
}

#myHeadline #Tagline{
  font-size: 150%;
    color:#000000;
}
```

```html
<div id="mainContainer" class="headlineContainer" > 
    <div id="myPhoto">
            <img src="https://cdn3.iconfinder.com/data/icons/complete-set-icons/512/googleplus512x512.png"/>

    </div>
    
    <ul id="myHeadline">
      <li id="name">This is google</li>
      <li id="Tagline">Helps you search everything</li>
  </ul>
</div>
```